# Issues in passing key vault secrets to the Data.tf and referencing in Main.tf

Tags: azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I have created multiple key vault secrets in the Azure portal and trying pass them in terraform Data.tf. But i am not sure how to pass multiple secrets and refer in the main.tf. Can someone help on this.
My requirement is to pass multiple values in the Name attribute and refer in Main.tf

```
data.tf

data "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
    name                = "test-key-vault-cts"
    resource_group_name = "gcdmvrlyprd03-30cf06a8"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "admin_password" {
    name         = "admin-password"
    key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

Main.tf

module "location_us-west" {
  source = "./Modules"

  web_server_location      = "westus2"
  web_server_rg            = "${var.web_server_rg}-us-west"
  resource_prefix          = "${var.resource_prefix}-us-west"
  web_server_address_space = "10.0.0.0/22"
  #web_server_address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
  web_server_name  = var.web_server_name
  environment      = var.environment
  size             = var.vm_size
  admin_user       = var.user
  admin_password   = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.admin_password.value
  web_server_count = var.web_server_count
  web_server_subnets = {
    "web-server"         = "10.0.1.0/24"
    "AzureBastionSubnet" = "10.0.2.0/24"
  }
}
```

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I didn't get any response. So do you still work this issue? Or if it solves your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference a second secret via data, create a second block of code.

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "admin_password2" {
    name         = "admin-password2"
    key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can put the data sources together with the module `location_us-west` in the main.tf file. So that you can quote the `data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.admin_password.value` directly. I don't recommend you desperate the data sources from the main.tf file if you just want to quote the secrets without any other actions.

And for the secrets, you need to put the names for multiple secrets to get them from the Key vault. So if you want to get multiple secrets only one time, you can change the code like this example:

```
variable "secret_names" {
  type = list
  default = [
    "test1",
    "test2"
  ]
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name = "key_vault_name"
  resource_group_name = "group_name"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  count = length(var.secret_names)
  name = element(var.secret_names, count.index)
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

Then the output `data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.example.*.value` will contain all the secret values in a list.